# Can you have more than one variable contributing factor when splitting your dataframe into two groups? pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I'm working on the number of COVID-19 death cases by state and seeing whether a high state population contributes to a higher death likelihood from those who have caught COVID-19.

Currently working on splitting my dataframe into two groups, but the way I have things set up, that split would rely on two factors, not just one - ex. highpopulation_highdeath (this means the state population is greater than the median and the death rate is greater than the median) and the other group would be highpopulation_lowdeath (state population greater than the median and death rate is less than the median). Current code is below, but I keep getting an invalid syntax error. So I'm wondering if you can't split a dataframe into two groups based on two variables?

## Split the deaths_to_case dataset into two groups

```
highpop_highdeath = df.iloc[(df'StatePopulation' > 4342705.0), (df'deaths_to_cases' > 0.012143070253953211).values]
highpop_highdeath.name = 'States with a high population and high death rate'
highpop_lowdeath = df.iloc[(df'StatePopulation'> 4342705.0), (df'deaths_to_cases' <= 0.012143070253953211).values]
highpop_lowdeath.name = 'States with a high population and low death rate'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have two variables. By the way, could you share the error message?
Also, try this out:

```
highpop_highdeath = df.loc[(df['StatePopulation'] > 4342705.0) &  (df['deaths_to_cases'] > 0.012143070253953211)]
highpop_highdeath.name = 'States with a high population and high death rate'
highpop_lowdeath = df.loc[(df['StatePopulation']> 4342705.0) & (df['deaths_to_cases'] <= 0.012143070253953211)]
highpop_lowdeath.name = 'States with a high population and low death rate'
```

Comment: It just comes back as a SyntaxError: invalid syntax for the original. And it paints a red line underneath my first line, #Split the deaths_to_case dataset into two groups

Comment: I tried yours, and it gave back a NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I did not notice iloc. You use iloc only when you want to slice with respect to index. You can use loc instead. Sorry again!

Comment: Ahh, that worked! I always mix up when to use iloc/loc. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To combine multiple factor on your filter, you need to use the boolean operator `&` with each condition:

```
highpop_highdeath = df.loc[(df'StatePopulation' > 4342705.0) & (df'deaths_to_cases' > 0.012143070253953211), :]
```

Comment: I got an Invalid Syntax error with that unfortunately.

Comment: I always confuse iloc/loc when to use - thanks for fixing! I just took out the , : at the end and it worked. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You want to combine the two Boolean vectors. This way for each position in the dataframe, pandas will evaluate both statements and only if both are true, keep the data.

```
highpop_highdeath = df.loc[(df'StatePopulation' > 4342705.0) & (df'deaths_to_cases' > 0.012143070253953211)]

ighpop_lowdeath = df.loc[(df'StatePopulation'> 4342705.0) & (df'deaths_to_cases' <= 0.012143070253953211)]
```

Even more succinct:

```
highpop_highdeath_names = df.loc[(df'StatePopulation' > 4342705.0) & (df'deaths_to_cases' > 0.012143070253953211),'name']
```

Comment: If you could please select the answer you found most helpful as correct, that will help future coders that have the same question